# Push Messages to Websocket Outbount using Spring Integration

Tags: websocket, push-notification, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I am stucking on experiment with spring integration and web socket. I have to say, web sockets are really new to me, and maybe I didn`t understand few basics yet.

What I want to do. My backend are generating messages and put them through the Spring-Integration systems. That works all fine. My idea is, and I am not sure that works. I have a channel where at least the messages arrive, a publish-subscriber-channel. Now I want to use a int-websocket.outbound-channel-adapter for pushing that messages to a browser.

My publish-subscriber-channel is named `ticketOutgoingChannel`

My configuration looks like follows:

```
<bean id="webSocketSessionStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.SimpleMetadataStore"/>

<int-websocket:server-container id="serverWebSocketContainer" path="sass">
    <int-websocket:sockjs />
</int-websocket:server-container>

<int:chain input-channel="ticketOutgoingChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header 
            name="#{T(org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor).SESSION_ID_HEADER}"
            expression="webSocketSessionStore.sessionId"
        />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int-websocket:outbound-channel-adapter container="serverWebSocketContainer" />
</int:chain>
```

One of my issues now, I don`t know how to get a sessionId for Websocket and if I have it, how to add it to message.

This is the channel, where the messages arrived what I would like to push to client.

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel 
    id="ticketOutgoingChannel" 
    datatype="...model.Ticket"
/>
```

Please provide hints in xml. I prefer xml cos of STS graphical support for better understanding. Later I am sure I will use then Java-Config.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, find the [WebSocket Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/web-sockets/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/websocket/standard/server/Application.java) to consider for your use case.

Before pushing to the Browser it must connect. I do that in the sample with simple JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/time');
    sock.onopen = function () {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'Connecting...';
    };
    sock.onmessage = function (e) {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = e.data;
    };
    sock.onclose = function () {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Server closed connection or hasn't been started";
    };
</script>
```

When sessions are connected to the server you can obtain all of them from the 
`serverWebSocketContainer.getSessions()`.

Then you can iterate (`<splitter>`) over them and apply your `<int:header-enricher>`.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for your answer. I checked that example already and I guess it could be helpful. When I have time again, I will have a closer check and will response then. Thanks for patients :-)